# Can I restore the files that I have deleted in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, netbeans, ide

I'm working on eclipse and sometimes I have to delete some lines of code that indeed I prefer to backup on a notepad file (because I never know if that lines of code could be useful in another moment), so I have to select all the code I have to delete, ctrl+x, open a text editor, ctrl+v, and save it somewhere.

I was searching for a "code recycle bin plugin", so that I can select the code to trash, right click and "send to code recycle bin"; and in the future the deleted code is still there if I need it.

Comment: indeed the new title isn't really suitable for my question...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a similar effect by configuring your workspace `Local History` settings:

[image]

Comment: Effectively this could be a solution, even if it is someway different from what I asked. I think that the problem with this solution is that trashed lines of code are linked with a specific file and its history, while a recycle bin would not have this association, letting me navigate "actually not useful, but yet interesting" snippets of code. However is already something :-) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I'm gathering from your question is that you often modify code in such a way that you're not sure if it will work after you modify it. What you need is a [software versioning system.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning)

Often, because a coder may introduce new code that is faulty or introduces unnecessary defects, we need to revert back to the last working version. There is an easier way than "Ctrl+X"ing the code and placing it in a "recycle bin" for future use. Try using a software versioning system such as [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) for better results. The source code is available online, and you can get an account for free.

In short, version control system will stop you from having to juggle files unnecessarily.

Comment: I already use svn for my current project. The fact is that when I have to add functionalities to core of my software, I delete all comments, all lines of code that are not strictly related to core functionalities... This way I have a stronger control over code and I can add functionalities with less headaches :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar which will resolve your issue, the [Eclipse Remus project](http://eclipse.org/remus/). You can download the plugin via the [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remus-information-management). After installation you can open the Remus Navigation view in your Java perspective, select the code and drop the code into the Navigation-Structure of the Remus Navigation view. The dropped source-code will be saved.

Comment: I'm going to try that, even if I seems that it could be like "going on a mosquito hunt with a bazooka"...